# <circle> attribute transform: Expected number, "translate(NaN,NaN)" in D3 legend of Covid data tracker legend

Tags: angular, d3.js, maps, legend

I am receiving the following error when trying to add a legend to a bubble map in d3.

```
<circle> attribute transform: Expected number, "translate(NaN,NaN)"
```

The code that is causing the error is

```
if (that.type == 'Bubble') {
  legend
    .append("circle")
    .style("fill","none")
    .attr("cx", function (d, i) {
      return (
        that.legendContainerSettings.x + that.legendBoxSettings.width * i + 20
      );
    })
    .attr("cy", that.legendBoxSettings.y)
    .attr("r", function (d, i) {
      switch (that.scale) {
        case "Linear":
          return that.linearScale(that.linearScale.invert(d));
        case "Exponential":
          return that.expScale(that.expScale.invert(d));
        case "Logarithmic":
          return that.logScale(that.logScale.invert(d));
        case "Sqrrt":
          return that.sqrtScale(that.sqrtScale.invert(d));
      }
    })
    .style("opacity", 1)
    .style("fill", "black");
}
```

A demo of the problem is available at:

https://jcbowyer.github.io/d3-in-angular/unitedstates/Filled/Sqrrt

Full source code for the map is available at:

https://github.com/jcbowyer/d3-in-angular/blob/master/src/app/unitedstates-map/unitedstates-map.component.ts

What can I do to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in a different block of code where translate was being set to undefined.